# How to make Bower download resources listed under ignore?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have checked out the [angular-leaflet-directive project](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) using Bower. I noticed that the `examples` directory, which is present in the git repository was not downloaded. Presumably because it is listed in the ignore section of `bower.json`

I want Bower to download this directory. So I deleted the entry and tried updating the component.

```
"ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "src",
    "doc",
    <s>"examples",</s>
    "test",
    "*.md",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "package.json",
    "bower.json"
  ]
bower update angular-leaflet-directive
```

This did not help. There was another identical file: `.bower.json`at the same location as `bower.json`. Making changes in that file did not help either.

I guess Bower is using bower.json from the repo and not the local one.

Is there a way to override parameters from remote `bower.json` with those from local `bower.json`?
If not, what is the recommended way of downloading the missing directory?